# Maven can't find a package

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jhipster, talend

I create a job talend, then I export this one as a jar.

The jar with the class is added. (build=> build configuration=>library=>add external jar)
But, when I try the build the project I get these errors:

```
package demo.kosecleaninfileuploading_0_1 does not exist
package demo.kosecleaninfileuploading_0_1.contexts does not exist
```

What am I missing?
(I'm using eclipse, Jhipster (Spring-boot) )

Thank you!

Comment: Are you building spring boot project and want to add external jar.

Comment: Yes that's it, do you know what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add your external jar as dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>"external-jar-group-id"</groupId>
       <artifactId>"external-jar-artifact-id"</artifactId>
       <version>"external jar version"</version>
       <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/"external_jar_file_name.jar"</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

and include it in system scope by adding this

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks you for your help. I have a little, and stupid, question, how do I know the groupId and the artifactId from a custom jar?

Comment: Try it by giving any name, just put it in correct lib folder.

Comment: What do you mean by the correct li folder? I put the path from the jar file? I tried => <dependency>
        <groupId>freeming.kosecleaning</groupId>
        <artifactId>kosecleaning</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Users\FMC_08\Desktop\tmp\KoseCleaninFileUploading\kosecleaninfileuploading_0_1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>